# Exception while upgrading my application from weblogic portal 8.1(sp5) to 10.3.6

Tags: java, weblogic-10.x

I am getting the following error while upgrading weblogic 8.x code to 10.3.6. I am using the import wizard:

```
!MESSAGE Exception caught during upgrade of "weblogic.xml"
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: weblogic.DDConverter exited with non zero value: 1
at com.bea.workshop.upgrade81.netui.XmlFileUpgrader.callDDConverterProcess(XmlFileUpgrader.java:175)
at com.bea.workshop.upgrade81.netui.XmlFileUpgrader.upgrade(XmlFileUpgrader.java:93)
at com.bea.workshop.upgrade81.wizard.UpgradeWizardContext$FileUpgradeRequest.performSourceUpgrade(UpgradeWizardContext.java:820)
at com.bea.workshop.upgrade81.wizard.UpgradeWizardContext$SourceUpgradeTask.run(UpgradeWizardContext.java:1577)
at com.bea.workshop.upgrade81.wizard.UpgradeWizardContext.performSourceUpgrade(UpgradeWizardContext.java:276)
at com.bea.workshop.upgrade81.operations.SourceUpgradeOperation.execute(SourceUpgradeOperation.java:35)
at com.bea.workshop.upgrade81.appimport.operations.ProjectImportUpgradeOperation.execute(ProjectImportUpgradeOperation.java:73)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl$1.run(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:376)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:1797)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.runOperation(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:401)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.runOperation(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:352)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.doExecute(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:242)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.executeImpl(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:214)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.cacheThreadAndContinue(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:89)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.execute(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:202)
at com.bea.workshop.upgrade81.wizard.FlexibleDataModelWizard$1CatchThrowableRunnableWithProgress.run(FlexibleDataModelWizard.java:312)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:113)

!ENTRY com.bea.workshop.upgrade81 4 2 2015-04-02 16:33:29.405
!MESSAGE A fatal error occured while processing the upgrade request for resource: weblogic.xml. Upgrade will be terminated.
```

Can someone shed some light on this?

Bharat

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the weblogic.xml.  Try to isolate the issue by removing suspect blocks or stanzas of xml and rerunning the upgrade until it works.  First identify the problem block and then figure out how to deal with it.